# How to access nested JSON in JS?

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

So I have this JSON struture that I have successfully passed into JS:

```
{
"StepOne": [
    {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "1",
        "description": "How are you feeling?",
        "options": [
            {
                "opt_id": "1",
                "opt_desc": "Good"
            },
            {
                "opt_id": "2",
                "opt_desc": "Perfect"
            },
            .... etc
```

It goes on until PageFive and the amount of questions vary from 1-4 in each step and the options vary from null to about 10 for each question. I want to use this information to generate a multi step form in Javascript, but I can not figure out how to access the inner data. I can only find "PageOne", "PageTwo" etc. I am using this following code to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {       
        $('#show-results').click(function() 
        {
            $.post('json.php', function(data) 
            {
                var pushedData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);


                $.each(pushedData, function(i, serverData)
                {
                    alert(i);
                })
            })
        })
    });
```

Now I have tried these functions to get to the inner values:

```
var desc = pushedData.PageOne.description;

var desc = pushedData['PageOne']['Description'];
```

And inside the each loop I've tried stuff like

```
var desc = PageOne.description;

var desc = PageOne['description'];
```

It all comes out as *undefined.* Is there a way to iterate through each of the questions in each Page the same way I have done to iterate through the pages? And from there rinse and repeat to iterate through the options for each question? If I could access each level I should be all set for generating a poll dynamically which is the ultimate goal here.

I think this code is on to something (found out right after I posted). Not quite working though.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {       
        $('#show-results').click(function() 
        {
            $.post('JSAAN.php', function(data) 
            {
                var pushedData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                $.each(pushedData, function(i, stepData)
                {
                    $.each(stepData, function(j, questionData)
                    {
                      // Print question here
                           $.each(questionData, function(k, optionData)
                           {
                                // Print option here
                           })

                    })
                })
            })
        })
    });
```

Comment: You are trying to access `PageOne` but your example has `StepOne`... is that the problem?

Comment: Are you sure pushedData contains a correct JavaScript object?

Comment: Oh lol Sorry @JamesAllardice :)

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah. I changed the variable name for the example as I found out after making this that it's most commonly named as multi step not multi page. But that's not the problem. My bad

Comment: Added a code snippet that is close to the goal I think

Comment: pushedData prints out as [object Object]. And when I just .html'ed it out it turned out perfectly.

Comment: @Sllix sorry for misplaced tags :) Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be

```
jsonData.StepOne[0].description
```

since you have an additional `[]` array wrapper.

Depending on you structure, just omit the additional `[]`, then you can access all the Object Properties directly, it should look like this:

```
{
"StepOne":
    {
        properties
    },
"StepTwo":
    {
        properties
    }
}
```

however, it's okay to have such a structure - now you have to write `StepOne[x].prop`

```
"StepOne":[
    {
        properties
    },
    {
        other props
    }],
 "StepTwo":[{...
```

According to the code you posted, this might be what you want, since you have several questions per step(?).

The simple loop looks like the following:

```
for (var key in o) {
  if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + o[key]);
  }
}
```

A nested loop is more complicated though:

```
function loop(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
        if($.isPlainObject(val) || $.isArray(val)) {

            console.log(key + " is an Object");
            // object or array -> call recursively
            loop(val);

        } else {
           // plain value
           console.log(key + "->" + val);
        }
    });
}
```

Take a look at **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/BYWna/)**.

Comment: Any ideas on how to loop through it automatically with some sort of foreach or while (counter < length(this.options)) of some sort? I expanded my latest code snippet that probably illustrates what I am trying to do.

Comment: Works like clockwork, just have to study it so I can identify what level I am currently on to provide proper printouts. Thanks a lot! :D
Sorry for late appreciation but I went to lunch ;)

Comment: if (key == "PageOne" || key == "PageTwo" || key == "PageThree" || key == "PageFour" || key == "PageFive" || key == "PageSix" || key == "PageSeven")
     {
      level++;
      document.write("<br/>Level "+ level +": " + key + "<br/>");
     }
     
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

if (key == "id")
     {
      document.write(val + "<br/>");
     }

Any idea why the first works but not the second?

Comment: sure, `id` is a leaf and that's why the else branch is executed while you made the check in the if branch i guess?

Comment: Oh my god I feel stupid now. Ofcourse it was that lol. This is my 3rd attempt to make this damned poll, the two first did not work as expected so now I am getting blind easily. thanks a lot. Made my day <3

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the StepOne !== PageOne problem:

StepOne is an array, which holds an object.

That makes no sense to me, seeing as there should probably only be one step in StepOne...
...but that's just me.

So you'd have to go:

```
jsonData.StepOne[0].description;
jsonData.StepOne[0].options[0].opt_desc;
jsonData.StepOne[0].options[1].opt_desc;
```

et cetera...

Comment: It's just that each step has several questions, so I had to find a way to link the questions up to each step. Will try this, looks promising

Comment: In that case, you might consider writing a function that pseudo-looks like:  "for each step, for each question in step: current_question = Step[i];  for each option in current_question, current_option = current_question[j]: write_list_item / write_checkbox (current_option).   

In real life, it might be a little more involved, and I'd personally end up doing some recursion in there, to make life less painful, but if you think about what each "node" in the tree represents, it becomes easier to write out functions to deal with them.

Comment: I did use recursion as showed in an answer show above, just strugglig with keeping track of my counting variables.